# Where are the Bookmarks on the left side in the Epiphany Browser?

Tags: epiphany, web-browser

ElementaryOS is the first OS that could make me switch from MacOS to the Linux side, but... I don't like Firefox, I don't like Opera, I don't like Chrome.

And the Epyphany Browser has no Bookmarks on the left (you can not add it in the settings). So fast browsing and fast Bookmark hopping? Nope.

So, add the Bookmark list on the left side... and I'm in :-)

Answer (score 0):

Vivaldi has a sort of file tree bookmarks browser in a left side panel (where you can also toggle on or off an additional bookmark bar). It's Chromium under the hood -- so it's compatible with most Chrome extensions -- but it has some power user-ish UI features you may appreciate.

Comment: Ok, so I can install a Chromium extension in Epiphany?

Comment: I've seen... no solution, your solution is Chrome, but I want to use a Browser like Safari, so I have to use Epiphany, and I need the Bookmarks on the left side ;-) So I have to wait for the developers.

Comment: Yes, you can use Chromium/Chrome extensions.

Vivaldi is not Chrome. It does use the Chromium project's Blink rendering engine, as does Chrome. 

How is Epiphany like Safari? Anything other than the rendering engine? Do you have some particular attachment to WebKit? Or is that you're committed to using a browser that looks native to Pantheon, in the way that Safari looks native to MacOS? 

I suspect you'll be waiting for a very long time for that feature to come to Epiphany, as Epiphany is -- as far as I know -- intended to be lightweight, with few "useless" bells and whistles.

Comment: Or you can install [Odysseus from AppCenter](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.alcinnz.odysseus/) and ask for this as a feature request.